# How do I use a constant string as a Projection in Taleo Connect Client?

Tags: xml, taleo, taleo-connect-client

I have an Export created with Taleo Connect Client 17.4 that retrieves a list of offers from Taleo Enterprise 17.5.1.

```
OfferNumber    FirstName    LastName
101            Leesa        Rathe
102            Annabela     Purser
103            Mattie       Pietesch
104            Saw          Febvre
```

I want to modify my export to add an "*ApplicantType*" column that has a constant, pre-defined value of "*Candidate*".

```
OfferNumber    FirstName    LastName    ApplicantType
101            Leesa        Rathe       Candidate
102            Annabela     Purser      Candidate
103            Mattie       Pietesch    Candidate
104            Saw          Febvre      Candidate
```

I've tried using a complex projection `<quer:string>Candidate</quer:string>`, as well as concatenating two strings with a function projection, but each time the server returns a Workflow Execution Error.

**How do I make my Export query return a column with a constant string value in Taleo Connect Client?**

Export Query:

```
<quer:query productCode="RC1704" model="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" projectedClass="Offer" locale="en" mode="CSV-ENTITY" csvheader="true" largegraph="true" preventDuplicates="false" xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
  <quer:subQueries/>
  <quer:projections>
    <quer:projection alias="OfferNumber">
      <quer:field path="Number"/>
    </quer:projection>
    <quer:projection alias="FirstName">
      <quer:field path="Application,Candidate,FirstName"/>
    </quer:projection>
    <quer:projection alias="LastName">
      <quer:field path="Application,Candidate,LastName"/>
    </quer:projection>
  </quer:projections>
  <quer:projectionFilterings/>
  <quer:filterings/>
  <quer:sortings/>
  <quer:sortingFilterings/>
  <quer:groupings/>
  <quer:joinings/>
</quer:query>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `<quer:string>Candidate</quer:string>` if you change the export mode to CSV.

```
<quer:query productCode="RC1704" model="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" projectedClass="Offer" locale="en" mode="CSV" csvheader="true" largegraph="true" preventDuplicates="false" 
    xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
    <quer:subQueries/>
    <quer:projections>
        <quer:projection alias="OfferNumber">
            <quer:field path="Number"/>
        </quer:projection>
        <quer:projection alias="FirstName">
            <quer:field path="Application,Candidate,FirstName"/>
        </quer:projection>
        <quer:projection alias="LastName">
            <quer:field path="Application,Candidate,LastName"/>
        </quer:projection>
        <quer:projection alias="ApplicantType">
            <quer:string>Candidate</quer:string>
        </quer:projection>
    </quer:projections>
    <quer:projectionFilterings/>
    <quer:filterings/>
    <quer:sortings/>
    <quer:sortingFilterings/>
    <quer:groupings/>
    <quer:joinings/>
</quer:query>
```

Note that the export mode is "CSV", not CSV-entity. That might be what was causing your error.

Comment: Changing the export mode to `CSV` (labeled "*CSV-report*" in TCC) fixed the error.

Comment: What is the difference between `CSV` and `CSV-entity`?

Comment: CSV is working like a SQL script and that's what you want in 99% of the cases. CSV-entity will threat the data differently and will give information about the data language. When exporting a value that can be in different languages, the locale will be extracted along the data, for example: "en=data".